# The addition of two values in an equation but error occurred

Tags: react-native

const Rft = ((tubeOuterD * tubeFF / tubeInnerD) + shellFF)
setTotalFoolingResistance(Rft)

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgD2w.jpg

So the problem is that when I tried to add the above two values together, which is 0.00022172949002217295 + 0.0001, instead of the summation of the two values, they linked the both values together instead which is 0.000221729490022172950.0001, which have two decimal point inside. Can I know how I will be able to solve the problem?

Comment: giving a guess both are treated as string, or the first is string. Convert it into number, i.e. Number(tubeOuterD) * Number(tubeFF) and so on.

Comment: Also take note decimals are always a problem with any languages, JS is no exception. If you want to be precise checkout decimal.js. Sooner later you'll encounter it. :)

Comment: It works after I type Number in front :) Thanks!